# Search for artifacts 30d or older in JFrog Artifactory

Tags: json, rest, shell, artifactory

I would like to get list of artifacts which are created 30 days ago and before.

I have a script which it was providing with in time period bound, but where I need to change time in milliseconds every time. Its bit tough every time so I need to get list of artifacts which are created 30 days back with out modifying my script every time.

This is what i am using now

```
RESULTS=`curl -s -X GET -u <username>:<password> \
        "https://<domain>.artifactoryonline.com/<domain>/api/search/creation?from=$START_TIME&to=$END_TIME&repos=$REPO" \
        | grep uri \
        | awk '{print $3}' \
        | sed s'/.$//' \
        | sed s'/.$//' \
        | sed -r 's/^.{1}//'`
```

Answer (score 2):

Your best option here is probably to use JFrog's AQL and query for artifacts with
"created" older than X days, for example, you can use an AQL query like:

```
items.find({"created" : {"$before" : "30d"}})
```

You can read more about AQL in general and about "Relative Time Operators" specifically, [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Query+Language#ArtifactoryQueryLanguage-RelativeTimeOperators)

So, an example curl with a limit of 10 artifacts would look like:

```
curl -X POST -u <user>:<password> -H "content-type: text/plain" -d 'items.find({"created":{"$before":"30d"}}).sort({"$desc" : ["created"]}).limit(10)' https://<your Artifactory server>:<port>/artifactory/api/search/aql
```